# Activity Indicator not starting animation straight away

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I initialize an activity indicator and in a button press action I start it animating and call the next view to display.

```
-(IBAction) downloadButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Download Button Pressed");
    indicator.hidden = NO;
    [indicator startAnimating];

    if (addviewcontroller == nil)
        addviewcontroller = [[AddViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:addviewcontroller.view];

    [addviewcontroller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:addviewcontroller animated:YES];

}
```

When I press the button, the activity indicator doesn't start immediately. It starts when the other view is called. The indicator is displayed for a second, but when the button is pressed it takes some time to load the other view.

I dont know why the indicator shows for a second without starting.

Comment: Why do you add the addviewcontroller twice? You could try to create your addviewcontroller in an other method. Inside the action (downloadButtonPressed) simple show the indicator. Then you can perform a selector afer some delay (`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`). Inside that selector you can hide your activity indicator and create your addviewcontroller.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted it works as you and niko said. thanks a lot....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
-(IBAction) downloadButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Download Button Pressed");
    indicator.hidden = NO;
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}

- (void)showController {

    if (addviewcontroller == nil)
        addviewcontroller = [[AddViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:addviewcontroller.view];

    [addviewcontroller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:addviewcontroller animated:YES];
}
```

That should do the trick ;-)

*EDIT*

I just noticed that there is a problem in your code, you are adding your `addviewcontroller` twice. One by adding it as a subview of the actual view controller, and one by modally presenting another view controller. You should remove one of the statements from this function.

Comment: why not afterDelay:0.00001f ?

Comment: Should work either. The important thing is that the Indicator will start animating at the end of the function downlaodButtonPressed. So you have to delay the start of your presentModalViewController.

Comment: thanks niko, i got the answer from the question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710174/activity-indicator-on-button-click  as u said. once again thanks Niko.

Comment: @Niko i try as u said. it works when i remove the subview. but i need to give the transition style so can i remove the subview is there any problem there.

Comment: @Bala : no problem here, just remove the addSubview, and it will work fine